# How to bind an input to Vue instance after it is initialized?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple Vue app like below:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" id="text1" v-model="data1">
    <input type="text" id="text2">
</div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data1: 'some initial text'
    }
});
```

This is okay. The first input is bound to the model, while the second one is not.

Then at later time I want `input#text2` to be also bound to the model. How do I do that? It seems like adding the `v-model="data1"` to `input#text2` with Javascript later does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and noticed two things if you wish to bound second input to the model. I would recommend using different v-model, like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" id="text1" v-model="data1">
    <input type="text" id="text2" v-model="data2">
</div>
```

Also, when you initialise Vue, you should state a second variable like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      data1: 'some initial text',
      data2: 'some initial text 2'
  }
})
```

If you do it like this then everything should work fine.

Here is a [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-js-sr9vwy?embed=1&file=index.js) with source code.

P.S. I hope that I have understood your question correctly and given you a desired answer

Comment: I may have missed one detail. I want to bind the second input to data1 as well, just not the time when the Vue instance is created.